# Re-generate same simulated data set in a MC simulation study

Tags: r, random

Suppose I simulate a data set using

```
set.seed(1234); 
rnorm(100);
```

Later, I would like to find the `90th` data value simulated without re-simulating the whole data set.

- How can this be done?
- Does `.Random.seed` play a role?

While this may seem to be an overly simplified problem (especially when one could just run the whole code again), this type of problem occurs in more complicated `Monte Carlo` simulations where perhaps a 1,000 data sets are simulated and something goes wrong on data set #90. One would want to view data set #90 without having to simulate data sets #1- #89.

Answer (score 1):

So store the value of the then-current seed and start from there.

Comment: How the current seed can be saved?

Comment: It is a single integer number (see `help(set.seed)`), and there are many R functions to save and load data.

Comment: For example: set.seed(1); a <- runif(100). Is there a seed that would give runif(1) == to a[90] ?

Comment: The obvious way is to save .Random.seed along with each data set. That's what I do. A good and alternative idea is to separate the simulation from the estimation. (simulating the data is usually cheap compared to the estimation step.)